# Use a list of values to select rows from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let’s say I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3, 5]})
df

     A   B
0    5   1
1    6   2
2    3   3
3    4   5
```

I can subset based on a specific value:

```
x = df[df['A'] == 3]
x

     A   B
2    3   3
```

But how can I subset based on a list of values? - something like this:

```
list_of_values = [3,6]

y = df[df['A'] in list_of_values]
```

To get:

```
     A    B
1    6    2
2    3    3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Answer (score 2217, accepted):

You can use the [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) method:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5,6,3,4], 'B': [1,2,3,5]})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   A  B
0  5  1
1  6  2
2  3  3
3  4  5

In [3]: df[df['A'].isin([3, 6])]
Out[3]:
   A  B
1  6  2
2  3  3
```

And to get the opposite use `~`:

```
In [4]: df[~df['A'].isin([3, 6])]
Out[4]:
   A  B
0  5  1
3  4  5
```

Answer (score 98):

You can use the method [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query):

```
df.query('A in [6, 3]')
# df.query('A == [6, 3]')
```

or

```
lst = [6, 3]
df.query('A in @lst')
# df.query('A == @lst')
```

Comment: i wonder if `query()` is computationally better than `isin()` function

Comment: @Hammad According to Pandas docs: "DataFrame.query() using numexpr is slightly faster than Python for large frames."

Comment: @Hammad I did a little test and `query` is faster than boolean indexing for dataframes with >10k rows (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73762002/19123103) for more info).

Comment: how to control for case sensitivity with query?  In case you are searching strings.

Comment: @sheth7 You can use `df.query('A.str.lower() in @lst')`

Answer (score 26):

`list_of_values` doesn't have to be a `list`; it can be `set`, `tuple`, `dictionary`, numpy array, pandas Series, generator, `range` etc. and `isin()` and `query()` will still work.

A note on `query()`:

- You can also call `isin()` inside `query()`:

  ```py
  list_of_values = [3, 6]
  df.query("A.isin(@list_of_values)")
  ```
- You can pass a values to search over as a `local_dict` argument, which is useful if you don't want to create the filtering list beforehand in a chain of function calls:

  ```py
  df.query("A == @lst", local_dict={'lst': [3, 6]})
  ```

### Some common problems with selecting rows

##### 1. `list_of_values` is a range

If you need to filter within a range, you can use [`between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) method or `query()`.

```py
list_of_values = [3, 4, 5, 6] # a range of values

df[df['A'].between(3, 6)]  # or
df.query('3<=A<=6')
```

##### 2. Return `df` in the order of `list_of_values`

In the OP, the values in `list_of_values` don't appear in that order in `df`. If you want `df` to return in the order they appear in `list_of_values`, i.e. "sort" by `list_of_values`, use `loc`.

```py
list_of_values = [3, 6]
df.set_index('A').loc[list_of_values].reset_index()
```

If you want to retain the old index, you can use the following.

```py
list_of_values = [3, 6, 3]
df.reset_index().set_index('A').loc[list_of_values].reset_index().set_index('index').rename_axis(None)
```

##### 3. Don't use `apply`

In general, `isin()` and `query()` are the best methods for this task; there's no need for `apply()`. For example, for function `f(A) = 2*A - 5` on column `A`, both `isin()` and `query()` work much more efficiently:

```py
df[(2*df['A']-5).isin(list_of_values)]         # or
df[df['A'].mul(2).sub(5).isin(list_of_values)] # or
df.query("A.mul(2).sub(5) in @list_of_values")
```

##### 4. Select rows not in `list_of_values`

To select rows not in `list_of_values`, negate `isin()`/`in`:

```py
df[~df['A'].isin(list_of_values)]
df.query("A not in @list_of_values")  # df.query("A != @list_of_values")
```

##### 5. Select rows where multiple columns are in `list_of_values`

If you want to filter using both (or multiple) columns, there's `any()` and `all()` to reduce columns (`axis=1`) depending on the need.

1. Select rows where at least one of `A` or `B` is in `list_of_values`:

   ```py
   df[df[['A','B']].isin(list_of_values).any(1)]
   df.query("A in @list_of_values or B in @list_of_values")
   ```
2. Select rows where both of `A` and `B` are in `list_of_values`:

   ```py
   df[df[['A','B']].isin(list_of_values).all(1)] 
   df.query("A in @list_of_values and B in @list_of_values")
   ```

Answer (score 14):

You can store your values in a list as:

`lis = [3,6]`

then

`df1 = df[df['A'].isin(lis)]`

Comment: What's the difference between top answer?

Comment: if you have more values to filter, it is better to store them as `list` and filter that `list` from the main dataframe.

Answer (score 10):

Another method;

```
df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: x.A in [3,6], axis=1)]
```

Unlike the [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method, this is particularly useful in determining if the list contains a function of the column `A`. For example, `f(A) = 2*A - 5` as the function;

```
df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: 2*x.A-5 in [3,6], axis=1)]
```

It should be noted that this approach is slower than the `isin` method.

Answer (score 4):

Its trickier with f-Strings

```
list_of_values = [3,6]


df.query(f'A in {list_of_values}')
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answers are correct, but if you still are not able to filter out rows as expected, make sure both DataFrames' columns have the same `dtype`.

```py
source = source.astype({1: 'int64'})
to_rem = to_rem.astype({'some col': 'int64'})

works = source[~source[1].isin(to_rem['some col'])]
```

Took me long enough.

Answer (score 1):

A non pandas solution that compares in terms of speed may be:

```
filtered_column = set(df.A) - set(list_list_of_values)
```