# Using pandas to select rows using two different columns from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Q is similar to this:
[use a list of values to select rows from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

I want to dataframe if either value in two columns are in a list.
Return both columns (combine results of #1 and #4.

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *


d = {'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4] ,'two' : [5., 6., 7., 8.],'three' : [9., 16., 17., 18.]}

df = DataFrame(d)
print df

checkList = [1,7]

print df[df.one == 1 ]#1
print df[df.one == 7 ]#2
print df[df.two == 1 ]#3
print df[df.two == 7 ]#4

#print df[df.one == 1 or df.two ==7]
print df[df.one.isin(checkList)]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You nearly had it, but you have to use the ["bitwise or"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html#numpy.bitwise_or) operator:

```
In [6]: df[(df.one == 1) | (df.two == 7)]
Out[6]: 
   one  three  two
0    1      9    5
2    3     17    7

In [7]: df[(df.one.isin(checkList)) | (df.two.isin(checkList))]
Out[7]: 
   one  three  two
0    1      9    5
2    3     17    7
```