# Selecting multiple (neighboring) rows conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to return the rows which qualify to a certain condition. I can do this for a single row, but I need this for multiple rows combined. For example 'light green' qualifies to 'XYZ' being positive and 'total' > 10, where 'Red' does not. When I combine a neighbouring row or rows, it does => 'dark green'. Can I achieve this going over all the rows and not return duplicate rows?

```
N = 1000

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'X':np.random.uniform(-3,10,N),
     'Y':np.random.uniform(-3,10,N),
     'Z':np.random.uniform(-3,10,N),
    })

df['total'] = df.X + df.Y + df.Z

df.head(10)
```

[image]

EDIT;

Desired output is 'XYZ'> 0 and 'total' > 10

Comment: what is the desired output and criteria?

Comment: `df[(df.X > 0) & (df.Y > 0) & (df.Z > 0) &  (df.total > 10)]` have you tried this?

Comment: put in an EDIT, mind you the problem here is combining consecutive rows that qualify the condition. In my example it should return all rows in 'dark green', even though they have negative values.

Comment: try the the solution I posted above , does it work? What is the solution you're trying?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pandas to select rows using two different columns from dataframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937022/using-pandas-to-select-rows-using-two-different-columns-from-dataframe)

Comment: No, it isn't. The function should check multiple rows at once if they qualify as a set. So 'XYZ' are summed for rows 7, 8 & 9 and then qualify and get returned, individually they do not.

Comment: @Zanshin I don't think I understand. What do you mean by consecutive row? Rows 7 and 8 obviously do not qualify since Y<0. Do you mean the product of X times Y times Z?

Comment: as a set, 'XYZ' in the example as a set. X7 + X8 + X9 summed >0 etc.

Comment: This is still unclear @Zanshin. You mean to say any combination of three rows where the sum of X + Y + Z is greater than 10 and each of X, Y, Z is positive? If so, you may want to think about `itertools.combinations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a try.  You would maybe want to use `rolling` or `expanding` (for speed and elegance) instead of explicitly looping with `range`, but I did it that way so as to be able to print out the rows being used to calculate each boolean.

```
df = df[['X','Y','Z']]    # remove the "total" column in order
                          # to make the syntax a little cleaner

df = df.head(4)           # keep the example more manageable

for i in range(len(df)):
    for k in range( i+1, len(df)+1 ):
        df_sum = df[i:k].sum()
        print( "rows", i, "to", k, (df_sum>0).all() & (df_sum.sum()>10) )

rows 0 to 1 True
rows 0 to 2 True
rows 0 to 3 True
rows 0 to 4 True
rows 1 to 2 False
rows 1 to 3 True
rows 1 to 4 True
rows 2 to 3 True
rows 2 to 4 True
rows 3 to 4 True
```

Comment: yes all possible combinations  for neighbouring rows (2,3..n) note: the rows can be viewed as bins. So, consecutive rows form a larger bin.

Answer (score -1):

I am not too sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you are looking to put multiple conditions within a dataframe, you can consider this approach:

`new_df = df[(df["X"] > 0) & (df["Y"] < 0)]`

The `&` condition is for AND, while replacing that with `|` is for OR condition. Do remember to put the different conditions in `()`.

Lastly, if you want to remove duplicates, you can use this

`new_df.drop_duplicates()`

You can find more information about this function at here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Hope my answer is useful to you.