# Selecting rows in a MultiIndexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to extract the bins for 'S' individually, where each column (X&Y) > 0.5, or multiple bins > 0.5 * 'number of rows'.

In the example;

for 'AR1' should only bin 4 be selected, because 'X' and 'Y' are > 0.5 (blue indicated)

for 'PO1' should bins 1, 2, 3 and 4 be selected, because 'X' and 'Y' are > (4 * 0.5) (yellow indicated).

I've tried this earlier with a `for loop`, but that didn't work correctly;
[Selecting multiple (neighboring) rows conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590518/selecting-multiple-neighboring-rows-conditionally)

```
np.random.seed(0)

N = 20
S = ['AR1', 'PO1']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'X':np.random.uniform(-1,1,N),
     'Y':np.random.uniform(-1,1,N),
     'S':np.random.choice(S,N),
    })

df['bins_X'] = df.groupby('S')['X'].apply(pd.qcut, q=5, labels=np.arange(5))    # create bins per column 'S'

def func(df):                                                                   # create function to group per 'S' and their bins
    df1 = df.groupby(['S','bins_X']).sum()
    new_cols= list(zip(df1.columns.get_level_values(0)))
    df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
    return df1

print func(df)
```

[image]

EDIT

What it should look like is the df as shown in the question, but the rows that do not qualify filtered out. What I check for is this ; the values in X and Y > 0.5 for any row(bin) separately or combined. Combinations of rows only consecutively, 2, 3, 4 or 5 rows combined.

I.e, the combinations of rows for 0 are then ; 0+1, 0+1+2, 0+1+2+3 and 0+1+2+3+4. For 1 ; 1+2, 1+2+3 and 1+2+3+4 etc.

Multiple rows would sum to the number of rows x 0.5, X and Y would have to be > 2.5 for rows 0 to 4 for example.

EDIT2:
@JohnE and piRSquared, both your solutions work, which one however would work better when there are other columns in the dataframe that should not be evaluated?

In addition, what if I would want to addin an additional condition in your solutions?

EDIT3:
@piRSquared, When subsetting some columns I only get those returned, where I would need all of them, not only the subsetted.

Could you assist? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a vectorized approach with only one loop at the top level (`groupby.apply`)

```
# columns that I care about
cols = ['X', 'Y']
df1.groupby(level=0)[cols].apply(find_window)
```

[image]

---

```
def find_window(df):
    v = df.values
    s = np.vstack([np.zeros((1, v.shape[1])), v.cumsum(0)])

    threshold = .5

    r, c = np.triu_indices(s.shape[0], 1)
    d = (c - r)[:, None]
    e = s[c] - s[r]
    mask = (e / d > threshold).all(1)
    rng = np.arange(mask.shape[0])

    if mask.any():
        idx = rng[mask][d[mask].argmax()]

        i0, i1 = r[idx], c[idx]
        return pd.DataFrame(
            v[i0:i1],
            df.loc[df.name].index[i0:i1],
            df.columns
        )
```

---

## Explanation

***strategy***

- [`numpy.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html): I need to evaluate each possible window for the rolling `mean` greater than some `threshold`.  I'm going to capture each possible window by starting from position 0 to 0, then 0 to 1 then ... then 1 to 1, 1 to 2 ... so on and so forth.  But I must always start at a position before I finish.  I can access these combinations with [`numpy.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html).
- [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html): It would be a little tricky (doable) to get the expanded arrays specified by each combination of indices that I get from `np.triu_indices`.  A better way is to calculate the `cumsum` and take the difference from one index to the next.
- I have to prepend zeros to my `cumsum` so that I can take the difference for the first row.
- But sums are not means.  I need to divide by the number of rows to get the means.  Conveniently, the difference between the end and start positions is exactly the number of rows and thus the appropriate number to divide the sums by in order to calculate the means.
- Now that I have the means, `e / d`, I check which are `> threshold` and identify which combinations of start and end positions have means greater than the threshold for both columns.
- I then identify the combination with the greatest number of rows among those that have means greater than the threshold.
- I unwind the positions and reconstruct a dataframe
- `groupby` and `apply`... QED

---

***time test***

[image]

---

***with more data***

```
np.random.seed(0)

N = 300
S = ['AR1', 'PO1', 'AR2', 'PO2', 'AR3', 'PO3']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'X':np.random.uniform(-1,1,N),
     'Y':np.random.uniform(-1,1,N),
     'S':np.random.choice(S,N),
    })

df['bins_X'] = df.groupby('S')['X'].apply(pd.qcut, q=20, labels=np.arange(20))    # create bins per column 'S'

def func(df):                                                                   # create function to group per 'S' and their bins
    df1 = df.groupby(['S','bins_X']).sum()
    new_cols= list(zip(df1.columns.get_level_values(0)))
    df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
    return df1

df1 = func(df)
```

The time difference is even more dramatic

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works. I've put in an edit. I need to use either your solution or JohnE's on my real data_set. This set however has a few additional hurdles for me.

Comment: Nice!  I erased mine as I knew it was quite slow and you included my code in the timings anyway, so if anyone cares it is there.  I had a feeling that this would not be easy to do in numpy, so I'm weirdly happy to see it was not easy!

Comment: I can appreciate the sentiment ;-)

Comment: @Zanshin I've updated my post to accommodate subsetting.

Comment: @piRSquared, if I want to evaluate for an additional column 'total' with a different threshold. How would amend your solution? 'total' would be 'X' + 'Y'

Comment: @piRSquared, I've tried your solution. I've put in an edit.

Comment: @Zanshin I've rerun my code with varying conditions and I can't replicate your error.  I can not guess what your issue is.  I also cannot continue to help without you providing adequate data to reproduce the issues you are having.

Comment: I understand. Could you maybe add a short explanation per code line, so I can maybe solve/change it myself?

Comment: @piRSquared, I've added a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094873/incorrect-results-when-applying-solution-to-real-data. Would you mind taking a look, thanks.