# Incorrect results when applying solution to real data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've tried to apply the solution provided in this question to my real data: [Selecting rows in a MultiIndexed dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833134/selecting-rows-in-a-multiindexed-dataframe). Somehow I cannot get the results it should give. I've attached both the dataframe to select from, as well as the result.

What I need;

Rows 3, 11 AND 12 should be returned (when you add the 4 columns consecutively, 12 should be selected as well. It isn't now).

```
    df_test = pd.read_csv('df_test.csv')

    def find_window(df):
        v = df.values
        s = np.vstack([np.zeros((1, v.shape[1])), v.cumsum(0)])

        threshold = 0

        r, c = np.triu_indices(s.shape[0], 1)
        d = (c - r)[:, None]
        e = s[c] - s[r]
        mask = (e / d < threshold).all(1)
        rng = np.arange(mask.shape[0])

        if mask.any():
            idx = rng[mask][d[mask].argmax()]

            i0, i1 = r[idx], c[idx]
            return pd.DataFrame(
                v[i0:i1],
                df.loc[df.name].index[i0:i1],
                df.columns
            )

    cols = ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']

    df_test.groupby(level=0)[cols].apply(find_window)
```

csv_file is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19oOoBdAs3xRBWq6HReizlqrkWoQR2159nk8GWoR_4-g/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT: Correct dataframes added.
[image]

[image]

Note: Blue frame = rows which should be returned, yellow frames is consecutive column values which are < 0 (threshold).

Comment: it don't seems to be a multi indexed table; Can you explain your criterion to select rows ?

Comment: Your code is difficult for me to decipher. Can you just explain the logic for keeping each row in plain english. Is that last dataframe your expected outcome?

Comment: @ted, explanation to the code is in the other question I mentioned. The last dataframe is what I get now, however row 12 should return as well. Criteria is column 2012.... 2015 need to be below 0, either individually or consecutively combined.

Comment: So, why is [3][total] a valid solution but not [3][2012]?

Comment: I got `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 5, saw 14` when reading the linked file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the way to modify the original question you were linking to, since your solution looked like it should work. However, this is an iterative way to solve what you're looking for.

```
import pandas as pd


df_test = pd.read_csv('df_test.csv')
print(df_test.head())
"""

   bins_DO    L  T2011   2011  T2012  2012  T2013   2013  T2014   2014  T2015   2015  Ttotal  total
0        0  IR1      6  -6.06     13 -3.22     12  -1.60      7  14.64     12 -18.20      50 -14.44
1        1  IR1     14 -16.32     12 -6.74     14  -1.22      5   1.58      8  -0.42      53 -23.12
2        2  IR1     10  -9.14     10 -0.42     10  11.84     13  -5.74      7  -3.10      50  -6.56
3        3  IR1      9 -13.78     14 -3.14     10  -2.48      6  -0.02      5  -4.78      44 -24.20
4        4  IR1      6   0.54      9 -9.40     15 -11.20      7   0.68      9  12.04      46  -7.34

"""
cols = ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']


def process_df(df: pd.DataFrame, cols: list, threshold: float):
    # initialize the benchmark
    # this gets reset any time the newest row fails the threshold test
    base_vals = [0 for _ in cols]
    keep_col = []

    for row in df[cols].values:
        # by default, keep the row
        keep_row = True
        for x in range(len(cols)):
            # if it fails on the row, then make keep row false
            if row[x] + base_vals[x] > threshold:
                keep_row = False

        keep_col.append(keep_row)

        if keep_row:
            # if we were happy with those results, then keep adding the column values to the base_vals
            for x in range(len(cols)):
                base_vals[x] += row[x]
        else:
            # otherwise, reset the base vals
            base_vals = [0 for _ in cols]

    # only keep rows that we want
    df = df.loc[keep_col, :]

    return df


new_df = process_df(df = df_test, cols = cols, threshold = 0)
print(new_df)

"""

    bins_DO    L  T2011   2011  T2012   2012  T2013   2013  T2014   2014  T2015  2015  Ttotal  total
3         3  IR1      9 -13.78     14  -3.14     10  -2.48      6  -0.02      5 -4.78      44 -24.20
11       11  IR1      7   7.10     10 -10.04      7 -10.60     17  -5.56     11 -8.44      52 -27.54
12       12  IR1     10  -0.28      7  -7.30      8   5.96      8 -12.58     10 -6.86      43 -21.06

"""
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the logic from your comment you are looking for rows that have every value in columns 2012,2013,2014,2015 less than 0 or have a cumulative sum less than 0. Since the first condition will always be true when the second condition is true you just test for the second condition.

```
cols = ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']
df.loc[(df[cols].cumsum(axis=1) < 0).all(axis=1), cols]

     2012   2013   2014   2015
1   -6.74  -1.22   1.58  -0.42
3   -3.14  -2.48  -0.02  -4.78
4   -9.40 -11.20   0.68  12.04
7   -3.12  -5.74   0.84   1.94
8  -10.14 -12.24 -11.10  15.20
11 -10.04 -10.60  -5.56  -8.44
12  -7.30   5.96 -12.58  -6.86
15 -10.24  -4.16   5.46 -14.00
```

Let me know in the comments if this is not what you want.

Comment: cumulative column wise, not per row. Please look at other question mentioned.