# isin check against a list-Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select some data from a dataframe based on a list. I have refered meany questions including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe) one. My 'df2' is like following:

```
   col1 col2  session_number col3 col4  session
0    1.1    A               0  1.1    X        1
1    1.1    A               1  1.7    X        2
2    1.1    A               2  2.5    Y        3
3    2.6    B               0  2.6    Y        7
4    2.5    B               0  3.3    Z        5
```

I want to group 'col2' and 'session' in to another dataframe.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'count' : df2.groupby( ["col2","session"] ).size()}).reset_index()
```

so my df3 is like:

```
   col2  session  count
0     A        1      1
1     A        2      1
2     A        3      1
3     A        6      1
4     B        5      1
5     B        7      1
```

Now I want to find session values where col2='D'.(these values are not here since I have put only part of the dataframe)

```
li = []
li.append(df3[df3.col2 == 'D' ]['session'].values)
```

Then I want to go back to df2 and get corresponding 'col1' values for the session values in 'li'

```
print df2[df2['session'].isin(li)]['col1'].unique()
```

It gives following Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nilani/Desktop/testingSessions.py", line 40, in <module>
    print df2[df2['session'].isin(li)]['col1'].unique()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/series.py", line 2785, in isin
    value_set = set(values)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

But if I use values inside 'li' as follows it wont give any error and print the output correctly.

```
print df2[df2['session'].isin([ 4, 10])]['col1'].unique()
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you li is a list containing an array:

```
li == [array([4, 10])]
```

Currently, looking `isin` li tries to see if something *is* the array with 4 and 10 (rather than included in it)... in fact it's worse that this since even looking to see if in li produces an error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

You want the more simple:

```
li == array([4, 10])
```

That is

```
li = df3[df3.col2 == 'D' ]['session'].unique()  # or values
```

**However**, in previous questions your session values were obtained by grouping by col2 hence this is going to be exactly the same as:

```
df[df['col2'] == 'D']['col1'].unique()
```

Comment: Thanks very much again..:). I was thinking too far doing this.