# Search for a row in a dataframe containing a string from a list

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to search for the `row` of which contains a string within a list.

`df`:

```
           Column1            Out1
0          ['x', 'y']         (0, 2)
1          ['a', 'b']         (3, 0)
etc.
```

I have attempted the following to search for the row that contains `'a'` in a `list` under `Column1`, as suggested in *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe)* answer:

```
print df['Column1'].isin(['a'])
```

With the expectation of such an outcome:

```
1         ['a', 'b']          (3, 0)
```

However, I seem to be receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need `in` for check values in lists:

```
df = df[df['Column1'].apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[['x','y'], ['a','b']],
                   'Out1':[(0,2), (3,0)]})
print (df)
  Column1    Out1
0  [x, y]  (0, 2)
1  [a, b]  (3, 0)

df1 = df[df['Column1'].apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
print (df1)
  Column1    Out1
1  [a, b]  (3, 0)
```

---

```
df1 = df[['a' in x for x in df['Column1']]]
print (df1)
  Column1    Out1
1  [a, b]  (3, 0)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again! ;)

Comment: Is one advantageous over another in any way?

Comment: Hard question, second should be a bit faster, but failed if NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

What you did in the beginning is correct:

```
df['Column1'].isin(['a'])
```

but you to wrap it with square brackets of the same dataframe.

here is an example:

```
threads = ['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444']
dev_data = train[(train['thread_col'].isin(threads))]
```

(dev_data) is a dataframe contains the results' rows.