# Filter a pandas dataframe by a list of column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

This is a subsample of my dataframe:

```
idcontrn    ctosaldo    fecanota    diamovto    fecopera    codsprod
491748      000         2017-08-25         3    2017-08-25         0
1014320     000         2018-05-28     99999    2018-05-28        33
1907630     000         2017-06-12     99999    2017-06-09        21
1573897     000         2018-01-25       613    2018-01-25         0
1713456     000         2017-08-08        17    2017-08-07         0
186315      000         2017-06-29        13    2017-06-28         0
150328      000         2017-10-23         1    2017-10-23        84
1531535     000         2017-04-25         1    2017-04-25        78
```

i wanted to extract the "codsprod" column's top 20 most frequent categories by occurrence, so i did this:

```
pd.DataFrame(sample.groupby(['codsprod']).size()).sort_values(by = 0,ascending = False).reset_index()[0:21]
```

which yields:

```
codsprod    0
0   0   319971
1   76  120026
2   33  62017
3   119 48138
4   14  42180
5   104 40756
6   48  26902
```

and so on... till the number 20.

Now what i want to do is to filter the original df by these top 20 categories of the "codsprod" column. I know how to apply filters to a pandas df based on a condition, but writing something like:

`sample[sample['codsprod'] == category_number]` just seems to tedious and long for me since i will hace to manually stablish 20 conditions, one per each category.

Is there a quicker and neater way of achieving this??

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `size` + `head` to get the largest `'codsprod'` groups. Use `.isin` to filter the original `DataFrame`. To get the largest 2 groups:

```
df[df.codsprod.isin(df.groupby('codsprod').size().head(2).index)]
```

#### Output:

```
   idcontrn  ctosaldo    fecanota  diamovto    fecopera  codsprod
0    491748         0  2017-08-25         3  2017-08-25         0
2   1907630         0  2017-06-12     99999  2017-06-09        21
3   1573897         0  2018-01-25       613  2018-01-25         0
4   1713456         0  2017-08-08        17  2017-08-07         0
5    186315         0  2017-06-29        13  2017-06-28         0
```

---

#### Explanation:

`df.groupby('codsprod').size()` returns a `Series` which is sorted in descending order based on the group size. The values of this `Series` are the group sizes, and the index of this `Series` is the corresponding `'codsprod'` value:

```
df.groupby('codsprod').size()
#codsprod
#0     4
#21    1
#33    1
#78    1
#84    1
#dtype: int64
```

Taking `.head(n)` will then return only the top `n` records, which in this case is the `n` largest groups. But note it doesn't deal with ties, it just takes whatever appears first (this wouldn't be too hard to include anything that ties also):

```
df.groupby('codsprod').size().head(2)
#codsprod
#0     4
#21    1
#dtype: int64
```

At this point, you don't care about how large the groups are, you want to know *which* groups are the largest. So you need the indices of this series.

```
df.groupby('codsprod').size().head(2).index
#Int64Index([0, 21], dtype='int64', name='codsprod')
```

This is basically a list of `'codsprod'` values, and to filter a `DataFrame` based on the value being equal to any value in that list you use [`.isin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe),

Comment: hey, thank yoy very much for your answer. Sorry, but why `head(2)` instead of `head(20)??`

Comment: @Miguel2488  For your real data you would use `.head(20)` Just wanted to show here that it will actually filter the original `DataFrame`. With `.head(20)` it wouldn't filter anything in this case (fewer than 20 groups) so it's not very illustrative.

Comment: Also just be careful as you can see here that it might not deal with ties how you'd want.

Comment: Thank you!! Please allow me to ask you a couple more of questions for the sake of learning and understanding. So instead of using slicing and indexing we can just use head with a specified value to get our desired number of results?? And i also guess that the filtering magic is in the `.isin` method right? And why use `.index` at the end?? what is this doing?? what do you mean with "ties"??

Comment: Really thanks a lot, the explanation couldn't be better, i feel i have a learnt a very important lesson about data filtering in pandas. :)