# Find values in one column that have association with certain values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tabular

I have the following example pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4'],
                   'B': ['b1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b6', 'b6']})
```

I want to find the values in A that have association with all of the values of an input list in B.

For example, for an input `lst = ['b1', 'b6']`, the desired output is `['a2']`. I have tried `df[df['B'].isin(lst)]` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe) but it is indeed not yet sufficient, or may not be even necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter `df` on each element of `lst` using a list comprehension

```
a_list = [ df.loc[df['B']==el,'A'].tolist() for el in lst]
# [['a1', 'a2'], ['a2', 'a4']]
```

The values you are looking for are the intersection of all lists in `a_list`

```
list(set.intersection(*[set(x) for x in a_list]))
# ['a2']
```

Comment: Accepted this answer because it is the fastest on my actual dataframe with ~ 2M rows, 1M unique A values, and 60 unique B values. The other two answers also work perfectly, but this one takes < 1s to run, while the other two take > 10s. Depending on your data/preferences, one may use any of the three.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it `groupby` + `filter` with `isin` + `all`

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(lst).isin(x['B']).all())
    A   B
1  a2  b1
4  a2  b6
```

Or

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.A,df.B).ge(1)[lst].all(1) # you have the series 
s # s[s].index
A
a1    False
a2     True
a3    False
a4    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `set.issubset` to check if one list is in the other:

```
m = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: set(lst).issubset(set(x)))
df[df['A'].map(m)]

    A   B
0  a1  b1
1  a2  b1
3  a1  b3
4  a2  b6
7  a2  b7
8  a1  b6
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one seem to be not correct as "a4" is also wrongly returned. The second one, seem to be working. I am checking for efficiency now on the actual large dataframe.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I made an edit. First solution should be also quite efficient now

Comment: It does not work on my actual data. I found this example now, for which, again it does not work for your reference: `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5', 'a2', 'a1'], 'B': ['b1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b6', 'b6', 'b7', 'b7', 'b6']})` the output should now include a1 and a2. But yours (first one) seem to return empty. The two other answers seem to be working, but I want to share this feedback with you.