# python pandas query for values in list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use `query()` to filter rows in a panda dataframe that appear in a given list. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe) question, but I really would prefer to use `query()`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3, 5]})
mylist =[5,3]
```

I tried:

```
df.query('A.isin(mylist)')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try this, using `@`, that allows us to refer a variable in the environment:

```
df.query('A in @mylist')
```

Or this:

```
df.query('A.isin(@mylist)',engine='python')
```