# How to check if pandas DateTimeIndex dates belong to a list?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a pandas datetime index `idx` with with minute frequency, I also have a list(or set) of dates `list_of_dates`. I would like to return a boolean array of the same size of `idx` with the condition that the dates of datetime index belong is in the `list_of_dates`. Is it possible to do it in a vectorized way (i.e. not using a for loop)?

Comment: use `isin()`  method so where you stucked?

Comment: try `df['flag'] = df.index.isin(l)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a list of values to select rows from a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to compare only the dates, you could remove the times and compare like so:

```
>>> df.index.normalize().isin(list_of_dates)
```

Or:

```
>>> df.index.floor('D').isin(list_of_dates)
```