# Why str.startswith() works on filtering but str.match() does not work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, startswith

I have a Dataframe in which there is a column of Mobile numbers (df1). Also, I have another Dataframe same as df1 with some of df1's Mobile numbers (df2). I want to extract the rows of df1 that have the same Mobile numbers in df2.

I created a tuple from df2 Mobile numbers (df2_mobiles).  I used this code for extracting rows in df1 containing df2 Mobile numbers:

```
df1[df1.Mobile.str.match(df2_mobiles)]
```

and received this error:
"first argument must be string or compiled pattern"

But when I use:

```
df1[df1.Mobile.str.startswith(df2_mobiles)]
```

it works.
However I need exact match of mobile numbers. Anybody can help me how I can do this properly?

Comment: Can you add osme data sample? Maybe need `df1[df1.Mobile.str.match('|'.join(df2_mobiles))] `

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link. I think it is answered here.
[Use a list of values to select rows from a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

You could use "isin" to find the exact match.

```
df1[df1.Mobile.isin(df2.Mobile.to_list())]
```