# Filter rows that are not in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that has a column of city names and a column with crashes (integer) column where the city column has a correct spelling but also has misspellings of each. I created a list of each city's correct spelling and trying to filter out the misspelled rows. But the code I've tried so far isn't filtering out the misspelled rows. My searches on how to do this lead to using isin.

Here is part of my city list:

```
city_list = [('Aberdeen', 'Ahoskie', 'Alamance', 'Albermarle',...
```

Here are some attempts:

```
df = df[~df['city'].isin(city_list)]
df = df[df['city'].apply(lambda x: tuple([y.lower() for y in x])).isin(city_list)]
df = df[np.isin(df['city'], city_list)]
```

So I want to filter out 'Aberdee' and keep 'Aberdeen' as an example:

```
               city crash_1
915         ABERDEE       1
97         ABERDEEN     587
916         ABSHERS       1
917            ACME       1
```

Much obliged for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a list of values to select rows from a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @MarkMoralls please update your sample data to a proper one and also your expected output. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

just you need to take into consideration the city name cases (upper.lower,captilize):

```
df = df[df.city.str.capitalize().isin(city_list)]
```

if your list is not flat and you have actually list of tuples , first flatten the list like so :

```
city_list =[item for t in city_list for item in t]
```

Comment: Changed the city to ABERDEEN in the list and substituted upper in the code but I get an empty dataframe.

Comment: @MarkMoralls noticed there is a parentheses at your city_list list , that mean you have a list of just one tuple , remove parentheses and you will be ok

Comment: Got rid of the parentheses and used df = df[df.city.str.capitalize().isin(city_list)] and it worked. Thanks! This issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that needs to deal with is the list of tuple of the cities. If you are not keen on keeping the tuple, you can remove it while capitalizing the strings.

```
newlist = [i.upper() for i in city_list[0]]

df[df['city'].isin(newlist)]
```

Comment: That returns with the values I don't want. How do I return the values that match the tuple instead?

Comment: @MarkMoralls So in your list, there are more than one tuple?