# Filter Data in Python

Tags: python, data-analysis

Among 99 Iowa counties, only the following 10 counties have a population close to or more than  100 000. Filter and name the dataset, so you only have the data from the counties: Polk, Linn, Scott, Johnson, Black Hawk, Woodbury, Dubuque, Story, Dallas, and Pottawattamie. Resent the index of the filtered data set. Check to make sure (using Python) you have the correct counties.

I'm not really sure how to select multiple county names all at once.

I tried to use the
ils[(ils.County == "Polk") & (ils.County == "Linn") & (ils.County == "Scott") & (ils.County == "Johnson") & (ils.County == "Black Hawk") & (ils.County == "Woodbury") & (ils.County == "Dubuque") & (ils.County == "Story") & (ils.County =="Dallas") & (ils.County == "Pottawattamie")]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLK56.png) this is all I'm getting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a list of values to select rows from a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isin`. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

`ils[ils['County'].isin(["Polk", "Linn", "Scott"])]`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you should use `|` instead of `&`, cause a country name should be either "Polk" or "Linn", not both.