# Remove multiple rows in df that contains these values - pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my first time posting a question on SO. I would like to learn how can I remove the entire (multiple) row of data, if one of the columns in my dataframe contained specific values?

Example: if column 'taste' exist, drop the entire row whereby country contains 'USA' and 'China'

Before:

```
     name   country       price
1    apple  USA           2.0
2    apple  China         2.1
3    apple  South Africa  2.0
4    pear   China         2.8
5    pear   Australia     2.8
6    pear   USA           2.5
7    pear   USA           2.6
```

...

After:

```
     name   country       price
1    apple  South Africa  2.0
2    pear   Australia     2.8
```

...

Here is what I written and it doesn't work:

def removeManyRows(df, column_to_check, removeValues):

```
// Check if col exist
if column_to_check not in df.columns:
    print(f"The column '{column_to_check}' does not exist in the DataFrame.")
    return df


for values in removeValues:
    // Remove rows
    df = df[df[column_to_check] != values]
print(f"Success.")
return df
```

I am rather weak in coding so would appreciate your help/advice here! Thanks!!

Comment: out = df[~df['country'].isin(['USA', 'China'])]

Comment: Please refer to the next post that Stack Overflow has recommended to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe?rq=2